# Core Data not saving changes to Transformable property

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am saving an `NSMutableArray` in a Transformable property in my Core Data store. I can create the entity properly with data in the `NSMutableArray` and then load it out of the property, and even make changes. When I go around my app and re-access it, my changes are saved. However when I reload the app, the changes have not saved in the core data store. Other changes to the entity - e.g. changing its title, which is saved as an `NSString` - are saved even when I quit and re-open the app.

I read in [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764046?tab=oldest#tab-top) that Transformable attributes are not automatically notified of changes, and that I'd have to call "the appropriate setter before saving". However even using the actual setter functions - I have also tried calling `didChangeValueForKey` - the property is not saved properly. Any good ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must, as you note, "re-set" a transformable property:

```
id temp = [myManagedObject myTransformableAttribute];

//.. do something with temp

[myManagedObject setMyTransformableAttribute:temp];
```

There is no way that Core Data could appropriately monitor an arbitrary transformable object so that it could 'do the right thing' automatically.

Furthermore, you must be certain that you actually save the managed object context after you modify the transformable attribute:

```
NSError *error;
if(![[myManagedObject managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
  //present error
}
```

During a single run of the program, unsaved changes will appear visible because the managed object context keeps modified instances in memory. Without saving the context, however, those changes will not be persisted to disk.

Comment: I've experienced this issue with NSMutableArrays as the transformable attribute, and I was accessing the appropriate setter methods and saving the context properly (other attributes were getting saved as proof). In my case the solution was to change the type to an NSArray.

Comment: @JoBu1324 Thank you for this, Took me forever to realize why stuff wasnt saving correctly!

Comment: @JoBu1324 I wish this was added as an answer instead of just a comment. It was the only fix that worked for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you not only need to re-set the property. But you also need another instance. That is why it wasn't working with `NSMutableArray`

```
Transformable *copy = [managedObject.transformableProperty copy];

// do stuff

managedObject.transformableProperty = copy;
```