# View controller is only filling in my form on the first save to coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c

So this is a little bizarre to me but I have a form that is filled out and can save to coreData and then be brought back up with the saved fields filled in. Everything is working fine except for a NSMutableIndexSet saved in a transformable attribute. It saves fine and reloads fine every time unless I save a second time then if I reload the page I get a NSLog of: `<NSMutableIndexSet: 0xe8b1800>(no indexes)`
 If I re run the app the saved data fills in correctly until I save again.

**edit:** I guess my real question is why does it take re-running the app to get my viewDidAppear to work correctly? Is there a solution for this?

**save code:**

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if ((self.form)||(formEdited)) {

    }

    else {
        self.form = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CookingSupplement" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    }
    // Update existing form
    [self.form setValue:@"Form 1" forKey:@"formType"];

    [self prepIndexSave:self.type.selectedSegmentIndexes secondMethod:self.type forKey:@"type" forIndexKey:@"typeIndexes"];

    NSLog(@"indexes being saved= %@", self.type.selectedSegmentIndexes);

      NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    formEdited = YES;
}
```

The NSLog always prints the correct indexes being saved.

**helper method:**

```
- (void)prepIndexSave:(NSIndexSet *)multiIndex secondMethod:(UISegmentedControl *)seg forKey:(NSString *)key forIndexKey:(NSString *)indexKey {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [multiIndex enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [array addObject:@(idx)];
    }];


    NSMutableArray *titles = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSNumber *index in array) {
        [titles addObject:[seg titleForSegmentAtIndex:index.integerValue]];
    }
    NSLog(@"new array::%@",titles);
    [self.form setValue:titles forKey:key];

    // now set indexes
    [self.form setValue:multiIndex forKey:indexKey];


}
```

**viewDidAppear:**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.type setSelectedSegmentIndexes:[self.form valueForKey:@"typeIndexes"]];

    NSLog(@"form type indexes:%@", [self.form valueForKey:@"typeIndexes"]);

}
```

**implementation:**

```
@property (strong, retain) NSManagedObject *form;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MultiSelectSegmentedControl *type;
```

This NSLog prints the correct indexes until save is pushed and the page is reloaded. This is corrected by reruning the app then it loads and prints the correct indexes that were saved.
If more information is needed let me know and I will add it.

Comment: Can you paste your viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear and other methods that go along with it?

Comment: Oops viewDidLoad was suppose to be biewDidAppear but that is all that I have for views appearing/loading I commented everything out in viewdidload and still same problem.

Comment: What line of code is outputting the NSLog(...) with "(no indexes)"?

Comment: @ReyGonzales In the viewDidAppear. When I open the view for the first time it says something like `<NSMutableIndexSet: 0x868b450>[number of indexes: 1 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (1)]` but if I click my save button and go click back then go back into my form I get No Indexes

Comment: To give a better idea of what I have: I have a tableview that loads all of the started forms, from there you can click a started form and it pushes the form and loads the saved data from coredata. When I save then push back and go back into the form everything loads correctly but these indexes

Comment: Can you provide the interfaces and implementations for your form/type objects?

Comment: @ReyGonzales I am using https://github.com/yonat/MultiSelectSegmentedControl for my segments. Another way I could accomplish what I am doing is to select the segments by title but I dont know how to do that with multiple selections

Answer (score 0):

I did it! after half a day I found out saving an NSMutableIndex to transformable attribute type causes problems and by adding:

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [multiIndex copy];
```

to my helper method everything worked!

[Link to Question and comment that helped solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057168/core-data-not-saving-changes-to-transformable-property)