# Inconsistency in Saving/Fetching Data in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

My first post here, getting straight to the point.

I'm facing a problem and I'm not sure whether is with saving of data or fetching it.
Here are my codes where I tried to save the data in my Entity, "Sequence". The entity consists of 2 attributes "seqForWk1CD" & "seqForWk2CD".

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
SequenceMO *seqEntity = [NSEntityDescription 
insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sequence" 
inManagedObjectContext:context];
// some other code
seqEntity.seqForWk1CD = arrForWk1;
seqEntity.seqForWk2CD = arrForWk2;
NSLog(@"%@", arrForWk1);
NSLog(@"%@", arrForWk2);
NSError *error = nil;
if (context != nil) {
    if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
```

When printed, the arrays will always display the contents of the array.

This is where I try to fetch the data.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Sequence" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
if(![context save:&error]){
    NSLog(@"Error fetching. %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if(count != 0){
    NSArray *fetchObj = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSManagedObject *sequence = (NSManagedObject *)[fetchObj objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"1 - %@", sequence);
    arrForWk1 = [sequence valueForKey:@"seqForWk1CD"];
    NSLog(@"%@", arrForWk1);
    arrForWk2 = [sequence valueForKey:@"seqForWk2CD"];
    NSLog(@"%@", arrForWk2);
}
```

The problem comes when I restart the application. The arrays either show (null) for both arrays or it shows the contents of both of the arrays. The if statement for `if(![context save:&error])` never gets triggered. Subclasses of NSManagedObject for the entity has already been added.

I've also tried declaring the AppDelegate in @interface and forced to save the context immediately by doing `[delegate saveContext];`.

Here is the method where the saving happens. "check" is initialized to 0 at the viewDidLoad method. Both "arrForWk1" & "arrForWk2" are declared at @interface.

```
- (IBAction)randomizeSequence:(UIButton *)sender { 
   NSMutableArray *storeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
   SequenceMO *seqEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sequence" inManagedObjectContext:context];
   BOOL record = NO;
   int x;

   for (int i=0; [storeArray count] < 9; i++) //Loop for generate different random values
    {
       x = 1 + arc4random() % 9;//generating random number
       if(i==0)//for first time
       {
        [storeArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x]];
       }
       else
       {
          for (int j=0; j<= [storeArray count]-1; j++)
          {
              if (x ==[[storeArray objectAtIndex:j] intValue])
                  record = YES;
          }

          if (record == YES)
          {
              record = NO;
          }
          else
          {
              [storeArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x]];
          }
       }
    }
    check++;
    if(check == 1 ) {
       arrForWk1 = storeArray;
       [self.wk1Seq reloadData];
    }
    else if(check == 2) {
        arrForWk2 = storeArray;
        seqEntity.seqForWk1CD = arrForWk1;
        seqEntity.seqForWk2CD = arrForWk2;
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (context != nil) {
            if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
        }

        [self.wk2Seq reloadData];
}
```

Just to add on, the arrays are of data type NSMutableArray and I'm trying to store them into attributes of type "Transformable".

Comment: Did you save your context after inserting the object?

Comment: let us continue this in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145523/coredataissue

Comment: When do you call the first snippet of code?

Comment: your storeArray contains nothing. You initialize your storeArray everytime you click the button and you are trying to save that array in coreData which contains no objects.

Comment: Please initialize the context only when you need, i.e. when value of check is 2

Comment: Why are you trying to the save the context when you fetch the data, it is there in the snippet you provided.

Comment: I thought it was for checking whether the object successfully fetched. But I'll try removing the `if(![context save:&error]){
    NSLog(@"Error fetching. %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}` in the fetch method and see if it helps.

Comment: Just tested it, the outcome was still the same. However, I've edited the question, added more detail to the type of array that I'm using. Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

After researching around I managed to solve the problem. I'm not sure how it actually works but I solved it by rearranging the code when I'm trying to fetch the data.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *descriptor = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Sequence" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
request.entity = descriptor;
NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchObj = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if(fetchObj == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error occured when trying to fetch.");

}
else {
    if(fetchObj.count == 0) {
        NSLog(@"No objects saved");
    else {
        NSManagedObject *sequence = (NSManagedObject *)[fetchObj objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"1 - %@", sequence);
        arrForWk1 = [sequence valueForKey:@"seqForWk1CD"];
        NSLog(@"%@", arrForWk1);
        arrForWk2 = [sequence valueForKey:@"seqForWk2CD"];
        NSLog(@"%@", arrForWk2);
        NSLog(@"2 - %@", sequence);
    }
```

I've tried also tried 2 ways of saving the data. In the `if statement` where I tried to save the data, I converted the `NSMutableArray`s to `NSArray`s.

```
else if(check == 2) {
    test2 = storeArray;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    SequenceMO *seqEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sequence" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSArray *tArr = [arrForWk1 copy];
    NSArray *tArr2 = [arrForWk2 copy];
    seqEntity.seqForWk1CD = tArr;
    seqEntity.seqForWk2CD = tArr2;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (context != nil) {
        if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
```

The second way I tried is by using an answer from [Core Data not saving changes to Transformable property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057168/core-data-not-saving-changes-to-transformable-property)

```
id temp = [seqEntity seqForWk1CD];
id temp2 = [seqEntity seqForWk2CD];
temp = arrForWk1;
temp2 = arrForWk2;
[seqEntity setSeqForWk1CD:temp];
[seqEntity setSeqForWk2CD:temp2];
```

Apparently it worked somehow.